# Is there a writing system whose word boundary is a non-space character?

Tags: writing-systems, word-boundaries

Is there a writing system that mainly uses anything other than space as the word boundary? Except languages with practically no word boundaries (e.g. Japanese) and programming languages.

I'd like to look into a language where I can write something like "Once.upon.a.time" almost for a whole book.

Comment: Japanese sometimes uses dots between katakana words.

Comment: This is not a property of a language, but of a writing system. The mapping between languages and writing systems is very far from one to one.

Answer (score 4):

In Ge'ez script (used for Amharic, Tigrinya, Tigre and Ge'ez) there is a word separator that looks like a colon.

Comment: True, although in contemporary Tigrinya - this is falling out of use, and shifting to a space. So is the usage of the question-mark character [፧] which is being replaced by [?] in most publications now. I suspect to a lesser degree this is the same in Amharic now, but to a lesser degree - judging from both Wikipedias for example.

Answer (score 3):

In Runic inscription we find a special word separator looking like ⁝